# How can i get the spider name in images pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I have many images pipeline but i want to use the different saving methods for different spiders.

I know that in other pipelines i can use `spider.name` but how can i get that in the image spipeline

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
   if spider.name  in ['first']:
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
```

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code? Where exactly would you need it and how do you call it?

Comment: i just need to check the spider name and then do something. I will update the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spider is passed as an argument to `process_item`:

https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline-example

You could either set a variable during evaluation for class wide usage, or implement a hook yourself if you need the spider before process_item is called.

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    spider = None

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.spider = spider
        if self.spider.name in ['first']:
            get_media_requests(item, info)
        return item

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        # whatever
```

You could also retrieve the info directly from the base class, which has an inner meta class `SpiderInfo` with a spider attribute.

see: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/media.py

Comment: imagepipeline don't have any `process_item` method

Comment: @user19140477031 yes it does, it inherits it from `MediaPipeline` see the [source at github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/media.py)

Answer (score 2):

`info.spider` is what you want.

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    info.spider.name
```

Answer (score -1):

Although it has been a long time since the publication, here I present a solution. Inside the pipeline, look for the name variable: spider.name

I hope you find it useful.